# Diagram library for adjacency matrix

Tags: javascript, python, visualization

Is there any javascript or python library for directly visualize [incidence matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_matrix) which draw arrows and nodes? Like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aSymmetric_group_4;_Cayley_graph_4,9;_numbers.svg).

Comment: Have a look at [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/). It at least has Python bindings, dunno about Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

For python, you can use [networkx](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/gallery.html).  The link is a gallery of graph visualizations, with associated source code.

For javascript, you can take a look at [D3 Data-Driven Documents](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery), another gallery of visualizations, some of which might be close to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just as mtadd suggested Newtorkx has a very complete library to perform network analysis and basic visualization. The igraph library is another possibility. For better visualization I would consider using Gephi (java based) which is pretty intuitive and easy to manipulate.

Here is a link for a tutorial to use [networkx](http://networkx.lanl.gov/networkx_tutorial.pdf) and a link for a tutorial on [gephi](http://gephi.org/tutorials/gephi-tutorial-quick_start.pdf%E2%80%8E).